# is it possible to run dbms_metadata.get_ddl and exclude column default value and virtual columns?

Tags: oracle, ddl, dbms-metadata

Example:

SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name, 'BOB')  FROM user_tables
WHERE table_name = 'APPOINTMENTS';

With various transforms renders:

```
create table "bob"."appointments"
       (
        "appointment_id" number(12,0)                   default "bob"."appointment_id"."nextval",
        "appointment_title" varchar2(50 byte),
        "appointment_priority"                          number generated always as <some logic> virtual
       ) ;
```

Can the default value and virtual column be stripped from the output?

Comment: Using quoted identifiers is considered bad practice as it forces you to use quoted identifiers (and the correct case) everywhere that identifier is used in the future. Wherever possible, you should use unquoted identifiers (as they are not case-sensitive). In your specific case, it results in an exception as `"nextval"` should either be `nextval` or `"NEXTVAL"`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use [`DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-0ACD6E3B-C699-469F-8CC3-32F9DA20CA60) to change the output for the `DBMS_METADATA` package.

Given the setup:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE "appointment_id";

create table "appointments"
       (
        "appointment_id" number(12,0)                   default "appointment_id".nextval,
        "appointment_title" varchar2(50 byte),
        "appointment_priority"                          number generated always as (1) virtual
       ) ;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
          'TABLE',
          'appointments',
          USER
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','APPOINTMENTS',USER) |
| --- |
| CREATE TABLE "FIDDLE_QANZBEWCAVFHDLPFZAAC"."appointments" ( "appointment_id" NUMBER(12,0) DEFAULT "FIDDLE_QANZBEWCAVFHDLPFZAAC"."appointment_id"."NEXTVAL", "appointment_title" VARCHAR2(50), "appointment_priority" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (1) VIRTUAL ) SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING TABLESPACE "USERS" |

and, if you apply some transform parameters:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'SQLTERMINATOR',
    TRUE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'PRETTY',
    TRUE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES',
    FALSE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'STORAGE',
    FALSE
  );
  DBMS_METADATA.set_transform_param(
    DBMS_METADATA.session_transform,
    'CONSTRAINTS',
    FALSE
  );
END;
/

SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
          'TABLE',
          'appointments',
          USER
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Then the output changes to:

| DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','APPOINTMENTS',USER) |
| --- |
| CREATE TABLE "FIDDLE_HKDFRKLPCSXVVQXILGQE"."appointments" ( "appointment_id" NUMBER(12,0) DEFAULT "FIDDLE_HKDFRKLPCSXVVQXILGQE"."appointment_id"."NEXTVAL", "appointment_title" VARCHAR2(50), "appointment_priority" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (1) VIRTUAL ) ; |

---

A full list of transform parameters is given in the [`DBMS_METADATA` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-0ACD6E3B-C699-469F-8CC3-32F9DA20CA60) and, to answer your specific question:

> Can the default value and virtual column be stripped from the output?

Using only the `DBMS_METADATA` package, no, there does not appear to be any transform parameter that would disable the output of the `DEFAULT` or `GENERATED` clauses for a column.

If you wanted to strip those clauses then you would need to do it after generating the DDL statement by rewriting the query (maybe using a simple regular expression - to look for, in the simplest cases, `DEFAULT` or `GENERATED` and remove everything until the next comma or the `VIRTUAL` keyword - or, in more complicated cases, by parsing the query to an Abstract Syntax Tree and pruning the appropriate branches).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AbKkD2L4)

Comment: The DBMS_METADATA documentation does not give the full list of parameters. There are several undocumented ones. 

They can be found in the METAXSLPARAM$ table in oracle.

However you appear correct in that there is sadly no transform parameter for this case.